# Extracting from multiple tables by id and ordering by created date

Tags: php, mysql

I`m trying to extract the activity of a user with a single query. I need to do it with one single query so I can use zend paginator.

I have 5 tables: `users`, `replies`, `threads`, `wiki_articles` and `wiki_article_revisions`. Each table has 2 common columns `created_by` and `created_on`.

I've tried using `left join` but I think what it returns is not correct and I'm unable to order all activity by `created_on`

Here is the join I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` u
LEFT join `replies` r ON u.id = r.created_by
LEFT join `threads` t ON u.id = t.created_by
LEFT join `wiki_articles` wa ON u.id = wa.created_by
LEFT join `wiki_article_revisions` war ON u.id = war.created_by
WHERE (u.`name` = 'CGeorges')
```

Comment: PLease provide sample data and desired results.  All we really know about what you want is that the query doesn't work.

Comment: I want to extract all rows where user.id = created_by from the other 4 tables ordered by created_on column which all 5 tables have this column. Everything in one query

Comment: For future code: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors, or to confuse single quotes and backticks.  The only reason you need them is if you have a name that is a reserved word, or you have embedded spaces or punctuation in them, and those are terrible practices to avoid anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thought process was wrong. I should have used UNION for this, like:

```
(SELECT id, name, created_on FROM users WHERE id = 1)
UNION
(SELECT id, name, created_on FROM threads WHERE created_by = 1)
UNION
(SELECT id, content, created_on FROM replies WHERE created_by = 1)
UNION
(SELECT id, title, created_on FROM wiki_articles WHERE created_by = 1)
ORDER by created_on DESC
```